# jira Estimation Story Points not show

Tags: jira

I am admin for a project in Jira and i create a board. when I create or edit an issues I can see the Story Points field. I have already config Estimate to Story Points in board configuration. But it doesn't work. What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be an issue with Screen configuration (where field is not added on screen) or field configuration (where field is hidden) or with custom fields configuration (where field is restricted to certain issue types or projects).

To debug this issue, Click on Edit on **certain issue -> Configure fields -> where is my field?**. and search for your field. Jira will let you know what is missing to display this field on that issue.

Comment: I'm not admin for Jira. I am only admin for a project. I don't found "where is my field" when I click **Configure fields**. ;(

Comment: I that case, can you explain what kind of board you have created and what do you mean by "Config estimate to story points"?

Comment: The Story Points field has to be on your Edit and View screens for you to be able to use it. The board configuration alone will not add the field to your screens. You need to talk to your Jira administrator.

Comment: Jira admin told me only 'Story' issuse have story point. But any way I found it and I can use it to estimate issuse for my team. Thank you all.